# I want to know why 'printf' and doit function is not working

Tags: c, pointers

Firstly, I'm sorry about poor English.
I make basic code.
I give a short sentence and my program copy this.
And I must use two sections(main.c and main2.c) and pointer function.
Surprisely, I make it for two days. but I don't know how to do this.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int retrian(const char *message);
int main()
{
    char data[30];
    int i=0;    
    char n;    
    
    do    
    {
        n = getchar();
        data[i] = n;
        i=i+1;
    }
    while (n != '\n');
    data[i]= '\0';
    
    retrian(data);
}
```

**doit.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int retrian(const char *message)
{
    char *ptr;
    for(int k=0; *(message+k)!='\0'; k++)
    {
        *(ptr+k) = *(message+k);
    }
    
    printf("%s is printing", ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define "retrian(const char*);" func as int and in doit.c you define it same type but func doesn't have "return". If you want to print something to console withour return it should have been "void"

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void retrian(const char*);

int main()
{
    char data[30];
    int i=0;    
    char n;    
    
    do    
    {
        n = getchar();
        data[i] = n;
        i=i+1;
    }
    while (n != '\n');
    data[i]= '\0';
    
    retrian(data);
}
```

**doit.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void retrian(char *message)
{
    char* ptr[50];
    for(int k=0; *(message+k)!='\0'; k++)
    {
        *(ptr+k) = (message+k);
    }
    
    printf("%s is printing", *ptr);
}
```

> when you type Ivan
> output is "Ivan is printing"

Please check the example

https://replit.com/@IvanBarayev/ExtrasmallIdealMode#main.c

Comment: It's indeed blindingly brilliant how much unnecessary work is done in `retrian` instead of plainly writing `printf("%s is printing", message);`.